# Java regular expression and pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a outlook message with body. I need to get strings of certain pattern **S15345,S15366** etc.

How can i achieve this in java?

I tried giving like below,

```
 String array[] = body.split("[S[0-9]]");
```

Comment: What Strings are you trying to create and place into in the array? And why not simply split on the comma?: `body.split(",");`?

Answer (score 3):

In this case better way is to use Pattern Matcher with this regex `S\d{5}` or if the pattern can contain one or more digits you can use `S\d+` instead

```
String body = ...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("S\\d{5}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    result.add(matcher.find());
}
```

If you are using Java 9+ you can use :

```
String body = ...
List<String> result = Pattern.compile("S\\d{5}")
        .matcher(body)
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```